# Cannot overrid Spring-Boot application properties in Junit Test

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, spring-boot, junit

I am trying override application properties, file is here: `test/resources/test.properties`

```
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:test.properties")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@WebAppConfiguration
public abstract class ApplicationAbstractTest {
```

But when I run any tests - they look for applicaton properties (and don't see VM options app.conf):

```
@PropertySource(value = "file:${app.conf}")
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
```

How correctly config this?

Comment: It works for me: '@TestPropertySource("/test.properties")'.
File 'test.properties' located in src/test/resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been solved after adding `ignoreResourceNotFound = true` to `@PropertySource(value = "file:${app.conf}")`